# Unable to update Bluetooth connection parameters

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to update the connection parameters of my BLE connection. My device is in peripheral mode and I am trying to connect to an IOS device. Right after the connection is established I tried to call

```
void QLowEnergyController::requestConnectionUpdate(const QLowEnergyConnectionParameters &parameters)
```

I received connection updated signal but the parameters are always the same and there is no update.
Here are the values I get

```
latency : 0
maxinterval : 60
mininterval : 60
```

I will be thankful if someone can provide some minimal example.